# Can I add and draw a component through code in Swing (Java)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, button, netbeans

I'm trying to add and draw buttons using merely my code. To be more specific, my goal is visualizing several buttons after another button has been pressed. This must be done programmatically because the number of buttons that have to be drawn depends on the user's input.

I've seen this piece of code in another thread and tried to implement it, but it didn't quite work:

```
// Adds a single button to a panel and paints it programmatically
private void jButton1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
    JButton button = new JButton();
    jPanel1.add(button);
    jPanel1.revalidate();  
    jPanel1.repaint();
}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Note: I'm using NetBeans 8.0.2.

Comment: Define "didn't quite work." What exactly is causing you problems?

Comment: my curiosity, why the MouseListener was added to JButton

Comment: The code is fine... depending on the layout manager of `jPanel1`. If it's something like `FlowLayout` or `BoxLayout`, it should work as intended. If it's `GroupLayout` (used often by GUI builders), I'd advice changing it to something that's more suitable for dynamic additions.

Comment: @kiheru Thank you sir! That fixed my problem.
Another question - how do I access and edit the created components' events?